# Suppose $G(x)$ is a CDF. What is the interpretation of $\dfrac{G(x)G^{\prime\prime}(x)}{(G'(x))^{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

This is an important function, but I am having trouble interpreting it.

(Obviously it's the ratio of some derivatives times the fuction, but what's special about this? What's the intuition in how to interpret it?)

In particular, what does it mean when it's less than 2?

Comment: One thing that pops out at me is that this is equal to $1 - \left(\frac{G}{G'}\right)'$.  But I doubt this is relevant.  $G'(x)$ is the PDF, but I don't think that there is any meaning in $G/G'$, for example.

Comment: That second term is the Mills ratio I think.  I've never thought about what the change in the mills ratio means...but this maybe helpful!

Comment: $\frac{G'(x)}{1-G(x)}$ is known as the [hazard function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Hazard_function_and_cumulative_hazard_function) and is the inverse of the [Mills ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio).